# Can't Install Picasa

Tags: google-picasa, picasa

Picasa is a photo gallery application that Google abandoned. I'm trying to install it on Ubuntu 20.10 and got an "unsatisfiable dependency" error. I enabled i386 architecture but nothing worked. I tried to force installation and have the following:

```
picasa : Depends: libc6-i386 (>= 2.2) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: ia32-libs but it is not installable
          Depends: lib32asound2 but it is not installable
          Depends: lib32z1 but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: ia32-libs-gtk but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You may find this article interesting. https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/09/ubuntu-32-bit-support-process-outlined

Comment: Interesting, but it doesn't show how to fix my problem.

Comment: Maybe they did not do the ones you need I did not read the name of every module.

Comment: I looked up one package, and it's not available on any supported release of Ubuntu.  I also believe I tried installing it long ago & it was a problem then due to dependencies (though do-able as I did it on my test system), but I decided it wasn't worth it (didn't repeat the install on my real system). Google abandoned it they said because better alternatives existed on GNU/Linux, and those alternatives were easy to install (being supported) so I never did it again.

Comment: @user26732 could you please share the installation deb-package (link or file)?

Comment: You are going to have to figure out what versions of those libraries are needed (the info from ldd may give a hint), fetch the sourcecode and build them yourself -or- see if you can find them in an older version of a Ubuntu repository somewhere. SInce Picasa is not OSS you have no chance of trying to build it towards newer versions of the libs. How technically inclined are you?

Comment: @N0rbert: Sure. I don't know which download sites are acceptable on this forum, but here it is: https://lilfile.com/hvPcof

Comment: I guess I'll try the Windows version and Wine. There are similar programs, but I don't know of any that will build a database immediately when you attach an external drive.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to simulate the process of Picasa deb-package installation on modern Ubuntu 20.10. It is almost impossible because of very limited set of 32-bit packages. And Qt4 is missed in the repositories.

So I would recommend to use PlayOnLinux with Wine to install the Picasa application. You have to:

1. Install PlayOnLinux

   ```
   sudo apt-get install playonlinux
   ```
2. Launch PlayOnLinux
3. Click Install
4. Search for Google Picasa in the wizard, click Install

   [image: Picasa in PlayOnLinux]
5. Allow wizard to download Picasa 3.9 from the internet and install it
6. Launch Picasa